# Check for DDR4 support on laptop

Tags: hardware, ram

As the question says, how can I check if my laptop's motherboard supports `DDR4-RAM` or not.

Laptop specifications:-

OS : **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** 
Product : HP Pavillion Series **15p045tx**

**P.S: Not mentioned on the HP website**

Comment: Details from ubuntu with `sudo dmidecode --type 17` likely will show what is IN the machine and not what is supported. Why not check the manual or your BIOS?

Comment: I tried that command and it showed me that the current is a ddr3, but it does not show what is not supported.

Comment: Motherboards, especially laptop motherboards, typically only support a single type of memory. So if there's DDR3 there, that's what it supports and nothing else.

Comment: @PrathuBaronia one of the main reason for this, is that DDR3 and DDR4 physically different is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your laptop only supports DDR3, no other DDR type.

[image: Memory for HP Pavillion Series 15p045tx]